# Example handling JSON with SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode6

I would like to handle json with SwiftJSON, but I stacked.
Does anyone show me example code?

I tried to use this library.
https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Although I placed SwiftyJSON.swift in the same project, I have error "No such module "SwiftyJSON""
So correct my code or show me example code handling json from web with swiftyJSON lib.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON // No such module "SwiftyJSON"

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://express.heartrails.com/api/json?method=getPrefectures")

        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)

        var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary

        var hoge = JSON(data)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Here is my Xcode capture

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It may be that you are just not opening the right file. Make sure you are opening the `xcworkspace` file, not `xcodeproj` file.

Answer (score 25):

If you added `SwiftyJSON.swift` to your project, you don't need to `import` it. It's already available.

Try:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://express.heartrails.com/api/json?method=getPrefectures")
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)
        if data != nil {
            var hoge = JSON(data: data!)
            println(hoge)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works well!
But I have a question.
Although the first parameter in a method does not need parameter name, why does we need "data:" in function JSON.
If I do not use the parameter name, I have trouble below.

Comment: if data != nil {
            var hoge = JSON(data!) // Cannot invole 'init' with an argument of type '@lvalue NSData'
            println(hoge)
        }

Comment: [`JSON(obj)`](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/blob/08e450aceeaddb46eff35a51c2b919b68b06903f/Source/SwiftyJSON.swift#L82) is to convert Swift object(e.g. `Dictionary`) to `JSON` object. [`JSON(data:dat)`](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/blob/08e450aceeaddb46eff35a51c2b919b68b06903f/Source/SwiftyJSON.swift#L67) is to convert `NSData` to `JSON` object

Comment: I got it! Thanks your answer with the link to SwiftJson source code which declares the definition of JSON function.

Comment: Ok, I did that.... but now I am getting TONS of errors telling me to replace "as" with "as!" al over the place. Why?

Comment: @Jose Shouldn't be. Are you using Swift 2.0?

Answer (score 9):

Use this https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON version to get up to date SwiftyJSON

If you want to use `import SwiftyJSON` then you need to add using pod
to do this, follow steps

1. Open terminal and run `sudo gem install cocoapods` to install `cocoapods`
2. From your terminal, go to your project home
3. Run `pod init` to initialize `Podfile`
4. Open `Podfile` and paste following command

`platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.2.1'
end`

5. Finally run `pod install` and it will add SwiftyJSON into you project
6. Close xcode and open `.xcworkspace` instead of `.xcodeproj`

Now you are good to go

For more info, [SwiftyJSON in cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftyJSON)

Comment: and build the project after that.

Comment: "6. Close xcode and open .xcworkspace instead of .xcodeproj" is enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

The issue I've had is not following [this bit of the CocoaPods instructions](https://cocoapods.org/):

> Make sure to always open the Xcode workspace instead of the project
>   file when building your project

I was opening the project instead of the workspace which resulted in the No Such Module error.

This went away after opening the workspace.

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is the link to a new Tutorial that explain very well how to working with JSON in Swift.

[Parsing JSON the SwiftyJSON Way](http://www.raywenderlich.com/82706/working-with-json-in-swift-tutorial)

Comment: Thanks! It's really useful page!

Comment: That example is only half done, it only shows parsing data not writing.

Comment: This doesn't talk about the SwiftyJSON library, it talks about a different Swifty JSON library.

Answer (score 0):

Api.swift

```
import UIKit

extension NSMutableData
{
    func appendString(string: String)
    {
         let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
    appendData(data!)
    }
}

class Api: NSObject, NSXMLParserDelegate
{

func CallGetApi(str: String  ) -> JSON
{
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://"+str)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    let data = try? NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil)

    if data != nil
    {
        let dataDict = JSON(data: data!)
        return dataDict
    }
    return JSON(integerLiteral:5)
}

func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool
{
    var Status:Bool = false
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://google.com/")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    let data = try? NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil)

    if data != nil
    {
        Status = true
    }
    return Status
}

func CallPostApi(urlStr: String , postStr: String  ) -> JSON
{
    print(postStr)

    let link = "http://"+urlStr
    print("\(link)/?\(postStr)")
    let url = NSURL(string: link);
    let cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: cachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0)

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";
    request.HTTPBody = postStr.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);


    if let data = try? NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil)
    {
        let dataDict = JSON(data: data)
        print(dataDict)
        return dataDict
    }

    if self.isConnectedToNetwork() == false
    {
        return JSON(integerLiteral:6)
    }
    return JSON(integerLiteral:5)
}

func CallUpdatePictures(urlStr: String , parameters: [String: String]?, pics: Array<UIImage>  ) -> JSON
{
    let link = "http://"+urlStr
    let url = NSURL(string: link);
    let cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: cachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 50.0)

    print(link)

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let boundary:String = "---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"
    request.addValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


    let body:NSMutableData = NSMutableData()

    if parameters != nil
    {
        for (key, value) in parameters!
        {
            body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
            body.appendString("\(value)\r\n")
        }
    }

    var i:Int = 1
    for pic in pics
    {
        let img:UIImage = self.resizeImage(pic, maxHeight: 216, maxWidth: 384)
        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)
        //let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0)


        if imageData != nil
        {
            body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\(i)\"; filename=\"image.png\"\r\n")
            body.appendString("Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n")
            body.appendData(imageData!)
            body.appendString("\r\n")
            i=i+1
        }
    }

    body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")
    request.setValue("\(body.length)", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Length")
    request.HTTPBody = body

    if let data = try? NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil)
    {
        let dataDict = JSON(data: data)
        print(dataDict)
        return dataDict
    }

    if self.isConnectedToNetwork() == false
    {
        return JSON(integerLiteral:6)
    }
    return JSON(integerLiteral:5)
}

func CallUpdatePicture(urlStr: String , parameters: [String: String]?, pic: UIImageView  ) -> JSON
{
    let link = "http://"+urlStr
    let url = NSURL(string: link);
    let cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: cachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 50.0)

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let boundary:String = "---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"
    request.addValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


    let body:NSMutableData = NSMutableData()

    if parameters != nil
    {
        for (key, value) in parameters!
        {
            body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
            body.appendString("\(value)\r\n")
        }
    }

    if pic.image != nil
    {
        let img:UIImage = self.resizeImage(pic.image!, maxHeight: 200, maxWidth: 200)
        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)

        if imageData != nil
        {
            body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"image.png\"\r\n")
            body.appendString("Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n")
            body.appendData(imageData!)
            body.appendString("\r\n")
        }
    }

    body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")
    request.setValue("\(body.length)", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Length")
    request.HTTPBody = body

    if let data = try? NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil)
    {
        let dataDict = JSON(data: data)
        print(dataDict)
        return dataDict
    }

    if self.isConnectedToNetwork() == false
    {
        return JSON(integerLiteral:6)
    }
    return JSON(integerLiteral:5)
}

func resizeImage(image:UIImage, maxHeight:Float, maxWidth:Float) -> UIImage
{
    var actualHeight:Float = Float(image.size.height)
    var actualWidth:Float = Float(image.size.width)

    var imgRatio:Float = actualWidth/actualHeight
    let maxRatio:Float = maxWidth/maxHeight

    if (actualHeight > maxHeight) || (actualWidth > maxWidth)
    {
        if(imgRatio < maxRatio)
        {
            imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
            actualWidth = imgRatio * actualWidth;
            actualHeight = maxHeight;
        }
        else if(imgRatio > maxRatio)
        {
            imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
            actualHeight = imgRatio * actualHeight;
            actualWidth = maxWidth;
        }
        else
        {
            actualHeight = maxHeight;
            actualWidth = maxWidth;
        }
    }

    let rect:CGRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, CGFloat(actualWidth) , CGFloat(actualHeight) )
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
    image.drawInRect(rect)

    let img:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    let imageData:NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0)!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return UIImage(data: imageData)!
}
}
```

Api class object:

```
var ApiObj = Api()
```

login Api call:

```
        let postString = "uid=\(Email_Txt.text!)&pwd=\(Password_Txt.text!)"
        var dataDict=ApiObj.CallPostApi("user/login", postStr: postString)

        if (dataDict.null == nil)
        {
            if dataDict == 6
            {
                 msg = "Network not available"
            }
            else if dataDict.object.objectForKey("token") != nil
            {
                 msg = "Successfull login "
            }
            else if dataDict.object.objectForKey("err") != nil
            {
                msg = "Invalid email or password"
            }
        }
```