# How to setup SwiftyJSON on my Swift XCode App?

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift, swifty-json

I am want to handle JSON on my Swift XCode app, I am stuck trying to mae SwiftyJSON work the first time.
So far I have done what appears [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754481/example-handling-json-with-swiftyjson), 
and I can access SwiftyJSON function calls from my code.
However, the code inside SwiftyJSON.swift file that I dragged into my project is now crawling with "Replace as with as!" warnings. 
How can I get rid of those warnings? What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `Replace as with as!` since you updated your `xcode to 6.3.1` and `swift 1.2`. You can use automatic assistant to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks! It is a hassle to change that, but it is good to know the reason why. Now it works.