# How to add third party library [Alamofire or SwiftyJson] Without using cocoapods?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, alamofire, swifty-json

I want to add a third party library in my project, but i don't want to use cocoapods due to some reason.

Can any one suggest.

Comment: Just move all files to your project directory and link with your target.

Comment: Official guide for manually add [alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#manually) & Manually add [SwiftyJson](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#manually-ios-7-os-x-109)

Comment: there is manually installation guidelines for thirdparty sdk ... you need to check that out

Comment: you can add manually. `download from the github ----> add all files to your project ----> then import needed file to your file ----> use it` . most of the github or third pary libraries have instructions and guidance for basic implementations.so read those carefully.

Comment: but it throws an error  **No such module "SwiftyJSON"**

Comment: did you import `import SwiftyJSON` to your working file

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754481/example-handling-json-with-swiftyjson

Comment: yes bro, i am trying same.

Comment: **you can use CARTHAGE these days**.  never use cocoapods, it's had it